# I cannot load tidymodels

Tags: r, install.packages, tidymodels

I get the following error after I try to load the tidymodels in my R studio:

> library (tidymodels)
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidymodels’ in loadNamespace (j <- i [[1L]], c (lib.loc, .libPaths ()), versionCheck = vI [[j]]):
> namespace ‘cli’ 3.1.1 is loaded, but> = 3.2.0 is required
> In addition: Warning message:
> package ‘tidymodels’ was built under R version 4.1.3

can any one help?

I look forward to hear from you.

best, Michael

Comment: remove and reinstall `cli` package. Then restart R and try again

Comment: Have you tried updating your version of the `cli` package? The error message says you have version 3.1.1 but at least 3.2.0 is required...

Comment: Try this: `install.packages("cli")`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to install tidymodels again using the pak package:

```
# install.packages("pak")
pak::pak("tidymodels")
library(tidymodels")
```

Keep in mind you may need to install some required libraries in your system.

Sometimes you need to restart the session when installing or updating packages.